# HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

when i am configuring jenkins agent in kubernetes under manage jenkins i add kubernetes cloud and configured kubernetes url when I  test the connection I got the below error how to resolve this.

[image]

[image]

i try to click the manage jenkins >> credentials config page i got the 404 error

Comment: 403 means access error, what does your configuration look like? Specifically with regards to credentials.

Comment: i have edited my post under manage jenkins i click credentials immediately i got 404 error.

Comment: 404 means not found, however, I believe in Jenkins if you are not authorized to access the page you get a 404 as well. The likely case is that the user you are logged in as does not have the necessary privileges to view credentials. Are you using an admin account?

Comment: In the unlock Jenkins page i gave the generated password from pod logs and then it takes me to user creation page where i create user admin. After login as admin user i tried to configure kueberntes plugin under cloud i just gave kubernetes url and jenkins url and test the connection it failed thats the first screen shot. again i tried to go to credentials in manage jenkins to create credentials i got the error second screen shot.

Comment: How to bypass unlock jenkins page which repeatedly loading . after creating admin user logged to jenkins page and clicked manage jenkins again this unlock jenkins page loading why that ? how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should lock down the access to Jenkins UI so that users are authenticated and appropriate set of permissions are given to them. This setting is controlled mainly by two axes:

- **Security Realm**, which determines users and their passwords, as well as what groups the users belong to.
- **Authorization Strategy**, which determines who has access to what.

You can check this [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/securing-jenkins/) for reference.

You might be missing this in your jcas configuration

[image]

Here is the [reference](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/values.yaml) for the screenshot above.